# Inject one service that uses methods from multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, interface

I am trying to inject an instance of a service into my `NameController`. The service uses methods from multiple service classes, so I'm doing this with multiple interface inheritance.

With the code I provided, using `_oneThreeService` I am actually able to access all the methods that `OneService.cs` and `TwoService.cs` contain. However, when I run the application, I get an error that states: `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ServiceClassLibrary.IOneThreeService' while attempting to activate 'Web.Controllers.NameController'.`

In the ConfigureServices method, I have tried adding this line `services.AddScoped<IOneThreeService, OneService, ThreeService>();` but that can't be done.

What I want is to be able to use methods from those two service classes by injecting only one service into the controller.

Startup.cs > ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddScoped<IOneService, OneService>();
      services.AddScoped<ITwoService, TwoService>();
      services.AddScoped<IThreeService, ThreeService>();

      services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

IOneThreeService.cs:

```
public interface IOneThreeService : IOneService, IThreeService
{

}
```

NameController.cs:

```
public class NameController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOneThreeService _oneThreeService;

    public NameController(IOneThreeService oneThreeService)
    {
        _oneThreeService = oneThreeService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _oneThreeService.MethodFromOneService();
        _oneThreeService.MethodFromTwoService();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to inject them separately. Either that or write your own class that contains them and inject that. You can't do this with registration magic.

Comment: Your posted code does not show any implementation of `IOneThreeService`. So exactly which object (i.e. of what type?) are you expecting to be injected there? As the code stands, it's actually impossible to ever fill in a `IOneThreeService` parameter or variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like you expect container to implement `IOneThreeService` for you based on fact the interface has no new methods and both base interfaces are registered in container - this functionality does not exist in any DI container I know, you need to register and implement such interface on your own.

Interfaces need implementation, just defining interface is not enough for compiler to find how it is implemented.

New interface also must be registered - there is no magic to find implementation of such interface.

Options:

- write class that implements `IOneThreeService` completely and register it.
- write class that takes implementations of `IOneService` and `IThreeService`, then implements `IOneThreeService` by forwarding calls to the corresponding service and register it (if constructor just takes interface the DI container will fill them baed on correspondingly registered base interfaces).
- instead of creating the new interface you can just implement both interfaces on the same class and register same instance for both interfaces

Comment: +1 Just to be pedantically clear for OP: DI frameworks require **exact** type registration. They do not use polymorphism to figure out which registered type fits best with the unregistered type you're referencing.